# java.util.InputMismatchException when reading from file

Tags: java, file

I get a `java.util.InputMismatchException` when I read the following information from a file:

> ADDRECORD CPCS-204 289 Rayyan Alzahrani 62 58 76

```
Student s = null;
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String command = input.next();
    if (command.equals("ADDRECORD")) {
        int ID = input.nextInt();
        String firstName = input.next();;
        String lastName = input.next();
        int[] examGrades = new int[nnmCourses];
        for (int i = 0; i < nnmCourses; i++) {
            examGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
            s = new Student(ID, firstName, lastName, examGrades);
            System.out.print(nnmCourses);
        }
```

Comment: On which line does that error occur? And it's not a compiler error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling

```
input.nextInt()
```

but the next token after `ADDRECORD` will be

```
CPCS-204
```

You need to read this token first, then read the ID field.

You might find it easier to use `input.nextLine()`, and then split or otherwise tokenize that string.